# Ruby install issue

Tags: ruby, macos, installation

I looked on my system (OSX) by doing a ruby -v and found version 2.06;  I also tried RBENV and the system said it was not installed.  I tried to upgrade ruby via home-brew and it did not find the ruby installation.  I then installed ruby via home-brew and it worked fine.  However when I invoked ruby it still loaded the old version.

My guess is that the ruby 2.06 is the system install and its higher up the path than the home-brew version.  Question is how do I ensure I can access the version I want (i.e. the newest install via home-brew - is it simply a case of accepting that two versions are there and when I invoke the home-brew version to use the full path?

Comment: Chris has great instructions at [gorails.com](https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.12-sierra).

Answer (score 1):

RBENV uses shims in PATH to direct your machine to use that version of ruby. It sounds like RBENV does not have that shim. Check out the [GitHub page for RBENV](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#understanding-path), specifically the section on understanding your PATH.